# Expression to create SSRS column dynamically

Tags: ssrs-2008, pivot-table, dynamic-columns, ssrs-expression

I need an expression to take an existing column and recreate this column over and over before another column/s where the column name contains either "Monday" or the date of the column falls on Monday.

The reason I need this expression is to repeat a header column in a pivoted report that is pivoting start/enddate parameter.  So if a user selects to run the report for this month, they should get 31 columns (for each date/day) and header repeating before every Monday.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your dataset contains all the dates in your date range. If not create a date table and cross join to it. Don't pivot the results, let SSRS do that bit. Once your dataset has all the dates, you can use a matrix in your report and drop the date colum into the column group. This will give you one column for each date in your dataset. I'm not at my PC at the moment but if you need any more help, show an example of your dataset and I'll put together a quick sample report.